# Why does this piece of javascript work on both Google Chrome and IE but not in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

I'm quite new to javascript programming and got stuck in this problem: I have a div displaying a map made with flash. This flash features a magnifying glass icon, that when clicked, calls this javascript:

```
function turnMap() 
{
    DivSwitcher(map.id);
    DivSwitcher(rightcolumn.id);
    DivSwitcher(leftcolumn.id);
}

function DivSwitcher(layer) 
{
    if (document.getElementById(layer).style.display != "none")
        document.getElementById(layer).style.display = "none";
    else
        document.getElementById(layer).style.display = "block";
}
```

All the called divs do exist, but the div with the map id is set with `display: none`. On both IE and Chrome, this code works just fine: the divs get hidden or displayed as I want, but on Firefox, it doesn't happen. I tried running with FireBug to see what happens:

> map is not defined

If you guys could give me any leads I would appreciate it.

Comment: Based on your code - map is not defined.  What is the variable map?  Same for right and left column.

Comment: This are divs ... I use the divs ids to retrieve them and then perform a style.display change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because the JavaScript variable `map` is not defined in the current scope, and that's all I can tell from your code.

My guess is that you are trying to access an element by calling its name, which is not supported. Maybe you can try:

```
    DivSwitcher('map');
    DivSwitcher('rightcolumn');
    DivSwitcher('leftcolumn');
```